# Quiet execution of download.file in install.packages in R

Tags: r, install.packages

The `install.packages()` function from the utils package in R has a 'quiet' parameter which reduces the amount of output, which is nice. However, it also uses the `download.file()` function under water and I'm not sure how to pass a parameter value to the `download.file()` function from the `install.packages()` function. I suspect I can do it by using the three dots `...`, but many subfunctions have `...` as an argument, so how do I send a parameter value specifically to the download.file function?

Answer (score 1):

From the help file for `install.packages`:

```
...     Arguments to be passed to download.file or to the functions 
        for binary installs on OS X and Windows (which accept an 
        argument "lock": see the section on ‘Locking’).
```

Looking at the use of `...` within the function confirms that it's only used to pass onto either: `download.file`, `download.packages`, `.install.winbinary`, or `.install.macbinary`

The other functions then pass `...` onto download.file eventually.

So just pass in your parameters that you care about and they will get used when `download.file` gets called.

Comment: Can you evaluate on how to implement this? There is a quiet parameter which I have set within the `install.packages()` function, however the `download.file` function does not inherit this parameter value. Would I then enter a parameter value for quiet twice in `install.pakages`?